# qooxdoo generator file name does not show up on errors

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I think that I have a syntax error somewhere but the qooxdoo generator does not say in which file .

even with the argument --verbose it just gives the following error

```
  Invalid control character u'\n' at: line 7 column 1 (char 117)
```

the full output

```
   >>> Processing configuration
  - Warning: ! Shadowing job "source" with local one
  - Warning: ! Shadowing job "libraries" with local one

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Executing: source::source-script
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>>> Initializing cache...
    - Checking path '/tmp/qx1.6/cache'
    - Using existing directory
  - Cleaning compile cache, as tool chain has changed
    - Checking path '/tmp/qx1.6/cache'
    - Using existing directory
  - Deleting compile cache
>>> Scanning libraries  
Invalid control character u'\n' at: line 7 column 1 (char 117)
```

any ideas how to find the where is this error ? (which file .)

Comment: I've never seen such an error, but it looks like perhaps your file is corrupt or maybe has the wrong line ending. Did you edit a lib file? Try downloading it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Qooxdoo does not return a proper error when lexical processing of *.json files fails (config.json, Manifest.json).

You might consider testing your files with [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/)